# MySQL: selecting value, which is not in db

Tags: mysql, select

I need to find first integer which is in some range (i.e. 2000 <= x <= 3000), which is not yet in a table's column. The idea is to select first value between 2000 and 3000, where (value + 1) would not be in a column. How should I write a query for that? Or may be there is a better way to find that missing value?

Comment: Can you explain in detail with table schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select 
   min(my_column)
from 
   my_table
where
   my_column + 1 not in (select my_column from my_table)
   and my_column > 2000
   and my_column < 3000
```

Comment: The question isn't entirely clear, but this will find the lowest value in `my_column` (between 2000 and 3000) where the value + 1 does not already exist in that same column.

Comment: This returns the lowest value that exists, _before_ a missing number, if you want the first missing number replace `MIN(my_column)` with `MIN(my_column)+1`.